# Validating fields in the domain class

Tags: grails

I need to validate the following fields in the given scenario:

This is my domain class:

```
lastName(blank:false, minSize:10, maxSize:50)
        dateofBirth

        address(blank:false, minSize:10)
        telephone
        socialSec
```

I need to validate the following:

1. `dateofBirth` - Can't be today's date or an advance date
2. `telephone` - Only digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement both using a number of constraints. However, the simplest is often the best.

For date of birth (using custom [validator](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Constraints/validator.html)) and assumes your date of birth is a `Date`.

```
dateOfBirth(validator: { val ->
  Date today = new Date()
  today.clearTime() // remove the time portion of the date
  val.before(today)
})
```

For telephone (using [matches](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/ref/Constraints/matches.html)) and assumes your telephone is a `String`.

```
telephone(matches: "[0-9]+")
```

I would recommend reading the documentation on [validation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/validation.html) as there are lots of ways to do this, and these are just two.